# Parsing issue with facebook data in fromJSON function (R) - unexpected character error

Tags: json, r, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull Facebook feed data from various pages to compare sentiment and I am running into trouble when converting the JSON raw text into a list object in R.

```
require(RCurl)
require(rjson)
access_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

FacebookScrape <-  function( path = "me", access_token, options){
  if( !missing(options) ){
    options <- sprintf( "?%s", paste( names(options), "=", unlist(options), collapse = "&", sep = "" ) )
  } else {
    options <- ""
  }
  data <- getURL( sprintf( "https://graph.facebook.com/%s%s&access_token=%s", path, options, access_token ),
                  ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
  fromJSON(data, unexpected.escape = "skip")
}

cb.path <- "24329337724/feed?limit=300&offset=0&__after_id=354707562896&"
cb.feed <- FacebookScrape(path = cb.path, access_token = access_token)
```

This code returns the following Error message:

```
Error in fromJSON(data, unexpected.escape = "skip") : 
  unexpected character: c
```

I'm not very familiar with JSON, but I know that the error is occurring in the fromJSON function (line 13 in the code above).  This function calls C, so using debug() doesn't tell me very much.  I'm also not really sure how a simple character "c" could cause an error if the JSON text is formatted properly.  It's not like "c" is an escape character or anything.  I also account for escape characters with the `unexpected.escape = "skip"` option in fromJSON.

I have determined that the error occurs when parsing [this post](http://pastebin.com/RpDYicgy) (there is no error if I set `limit=261` in `cb.path`, but there is if I have `limit=262`).  Has anyone run into a similar problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Session Info:**

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] streamR_0.1        wordcloud_2.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.10.2        stringr_0.6.2     
 [6] plyr_1.8           tm_0.5-8.3         twitteR_1.1.6      rjson_0.2.12       ROAuth_0.9.3      
[11] digest_0.6.2       ggplot2_0.9.3.1    XML_3.95-0.1       RCurl_1.95-4.1     bitops_1.0-5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-1 dichromat_2.0-0  grid_2.15.3      gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.1     MASS_7.3-23     
 [7] munsell_0.4      proto_0.3-10     reshape2_1.2.2   scales_0.2.3     slam_0.1-27      tools_2.15.3
```

Comment: This works fine for me using the example post.

Comment: When web-scraping it is good practise to separate your download routines from any processing.  That way when your code falls over parsing the JSON, you don't have to keep re-downloading the content and using up bandwidth.

Comment: To help us solve this particular problem, please provide the offending JSON string.

Comment: I am almost positive the offending JSON string is in the pastebin link that I provide in the original post.  I know it's a huge bit of text, but I added all the posts incrementally and the unexpected character error only showed up when I added this one.   Also, thanks for the tip on processing.  I'll keep that in mind.  http://pastebin.com/RpDYicgy

Comment: @Thomas - that's strange that it runs for you... I just checked it again and it's still not working for me.  I'll post my session info.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when pulling JSON data from Google Analytics. I never figured out exactly what was causing the error, but switching from the `rjson` package to the `RJSONIO` package worked for me. You might give it a try.

Comment: Yeah I've used that one a couple times. I'll check it out and report back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue... 
Base on callAPI from Rfacebook: https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/blob/master/Rfacebook/R/utils.R 
use: fromJSON(rawToChar(data)

```
facebook <- function(url, token){
  if (class(token)=="config"){
    url.data <- GET(url, config=token)
  }
  if (class(token)=="Token2.0"){
    url.data <- GET(url, config(token=token))
  } 
  if (class(token)=="character"){
    url <- paste0(url, "&access_token=", token)
    url <- gsub(" ", "%20", url)
    url.data <- GET(url)
  }
  if (class(token)!="character" & class(token)!="config" & class(token)!="Token2.0"){
    stop("Error in access token. See help for details.")
  }
  content <- fromJSON(rawToChar(url.data$content)) # It's working very well
  if (length(content$error)>0){
    stop(content$error$message)
  } 
  return(content)
}
```

Call facebook function:

```
next.path <- "https://graph.facebook.com/29092950651/posts"
facebook( url=next.path , token)
```

Your access_token will active over 2hours. I use fb_oauth base on http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/11/how-to-analyze-you-facebook-friends-network-with-r.html

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I have examined your JSON

the reason is here

"message": "true\",

this caused the json in R to be parsed and become \" and a missing quote disappears .

the next line can_comment triggers the error and it starts with C